# Unable to send email using "SMTP Authentication Support" module

Tags: 7, emails

I was working on a project where i  used "SMTP Authentication Support" module to send emails. The authentications i provided were my personal gmail account details, It was working fine. Now when i am entering the site admins account details its displaying "Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists." error. It also says that "SMTP Error: Could not authenticate." Can anyone let me where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the module [Mandrill](http://drupal.org/project/mandrill)

First you can go to [mandrillapp.com](http://mandrillapp.com) and create an account.

After account creation go to Api and generate an Api key.

Then after installing the module on drupal instance. Go to Configuration->Mandrill->Add the Api key and your site is ready to send mails.

Hope this helps.